# How do I create a large 2D vector in C++?

Tags: c++

The following statements run perfectly on my local Windows machine, but when I submit it online, (**on some online coding competition judges, not all**) it gives me a bad allocation error.

```
#define MAXV 100001
vector<vector<bool>> Mat(MAXV, vector<bool>(MAXV,false));
```

When I run my code online, it gives me the following error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Is it the proper way to define a large 2D vecotr?

Comment: These websites probably limit the resources available to submitted programs. Even with packed `vector<bool>`, that's well over a Gigabyte of memory allocated. Sure it's not a lot on your own pc, but if these websites are trying to run hundreds of programs at once, you can see why they wouldn't allow it. Do you really need all of that at once? Perhaps there is a better approach to the problem?

Comment: got it. Thanks for the very intuitive explanation. Will try to figure something else.

Comment: @BoBTFish is there any data structure in C++ which would allow me to store the same key but multiple values (for example - (2,3), (2,5), (2,100)) and with search time complexity O(1) or at least O(log n) in C++ STL? Apology for these naive question. I have recently migrated from C to C++.

Comment: `std::`(`unordered_`)`map` of `std::pair` with custom hashing function.

Comment: That sounds **semantically** like [`std::unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap), but that may store multiple copies of the key.

Comment: `std::multimap` and `std::unordered_multimap` are what you find. `multimap` is binary tree, and `unordered_multimap` is hash map.

Comment: I've heard some compilers may have problems with interpreting `>>` in `vector<vector<bool>>` as an operator, although I don't think that's the problem here. If it is, a solution would be to insert a space between them.

Comment: @sigvaldm That was required by The Standard to be interpreted as a shift operator prior to C++11, and as 2 closing brackets on a nested template instantiation since C++11 (some compilers did the latter before C++11 anyway, but It's been a few years and I can't remember which).

Comment: @BoBTFish Thank you so much. Unordered_multimap and equal_range() it is.